# Ajax Post data gets nullified on the server method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this ajax call;

```
var insertOrUpdate = function (url, callback, data) {
        $.post(url, data, callback);
    }
```

and the data is;

```
{"Companies":[],"HoldingCompanyId":3,"VatRegistrationNumber":"321-3123-45","Name":"gkjhgasdg g jghasfk jg","Created":"2017-05-23T00:00:00","CreatedBy":12,"LastModified":null,"LastModifiedBy":0}
```

On my controller I have;

```
public ActionResult InsertOrUpdate(HoldingCompany holdingCompany)
{
    ...
}
```

Where HoldingCompany is defined as;

```
    public class HoldingCompany : IHoldingCompany, IAuditInfoCreated, IAuditInfoModified
    {
        [Key]
        public int HoldingCompanyId { get; set; }

        public string VatRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        public int LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And yet when the data is posted, all the fields are set to nulls or defaults. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to set the `Content-Type` request header:

```
var insertOrUpdate = function (url, callback, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
        success: callback
    });
};
```

Here I have applied `JSON.stringify` on your `data` variable but this is only needed if it is a javascript object as shown in your question. If it is a string then you don't need to stringify it.